# spring boot application properties based on spring profiles

Tags: spring, spring-boot, deployment, profile

Hi I want my spring boot web project to be deployed both on development and production environment and it should be run on specific profile based setting.

I googled on how to do that, and first of all that I have searched is defining application-{profile name}.properties properly in the src/main/resources classpath.

Now the problem is how to set profiles.

Since I am working on tomcat 8 in linux, there should be some configuration but I don't know how to do that.

and I am also curious that when my project is packaged as war file, java -jar {filename} -Dspring.active.profile=blahblah will not be work, but I think there is an alternative way.

plus, is there an way to set profile on tomcat 8 in Windows 10 ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:**
I will recommend get rid of dedicated tomcat server and use embedded tomcat, jetty etc. Build your web apps as jar files and just run them. (of course if you don't have any limitations)

**Second:** You can do this either system property or env variable.

If you go with system property (order is important)

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=blahblah -jar {filename}
```

If you go with env variable you need specify

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=blahblah
```